# How can I connect Heroku ClearDB to MySQL Workbench?

Tags: heroku, cleardb

The clearDB 'How to Connect' page just says "You can connect with MySQL Workbench".

When I open MySQL Workbench and connect I need the following:

- Connection Method
- Port
- Host Name
- Username
- Password

I assume my username and password is the Heroku one, but what about the host name? Where do I find this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I assume my username and password is the Heroku one

Certainly not.

You should never reuse credentials across services, and ClearDB won't make that mistake. Like most database services on Heroku, [ClearDB provides an environment variable containing connection information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-shared-mysql-add-on):

> Retrieve your database URL by issuing the following command:
>
> ```
> $ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
> CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true
> ```

The value given here is a standard [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax), and you can pull individual values out based on that standard. In this example:

- User: `adffdadf2341`
- Password: `adf4234`
- Host: `us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com`
- Database: `heroku_db`

There is no port in this example, so you'd use the default MySQL port of 3306 (MySQL Workbench should know this and use it by default). If a port were provided, it would appear after the host, e.g. `11111` here:

```
us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com:11111/heroku_db
```